# How to change Spark setting to allow spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled?

Tags: python, apache-spark, configuration, pyspark, dynamic-allocation

I'm running a python script in pyspark and got the following error: 
NameError: name 'spark' is not defined

I looked it up and found that the reason is that `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` is not allowed yet.

According to Spark's documentation (https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-dynamic-allocation.html#spark_dynamicAllocation_enabled): `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` (default: `false`) controls whether dynamic allocation is enabled or not. It is assumed that `spark.executor.instances` is not set or is 0 (which is the default value).

Since the default setting is `false`, I need to change the Spark setting to enable `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled`.

I installed Spark with brew, and didn't change its configuration/setting.

How can I change the setting and enable `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled`?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Above link is not spark official documentation. Its Mastering Apache Spark Book by Jack who is also user of SO. please change it appropriately :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several places you can set it.  If you would like to enable it on a per job basis, set the following in each application:

```
conf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled","true")
```

If you want to set if for all jobs, navigate to the spark.conf file.  In the Hortonworks distro it should be

```
/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/conf/
```

Add the setting to your spark-defaults.conf and should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would like to enable it on a per job basis. conf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled","true")  is this a command line that I shall type in terminal? Which directory should I change to, before I type this command line? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're running from command line using spark-shell, start up the shell with is command:

spark-shell --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
It won't matter what directory you are in, when you start up the shell in com
If you're writing an application, set it inside the application after you create the spark config with the conf.set().

Comment: thanks a lot. I see. If I'm writing a Python script and try to run it with spark-submit in command line (not inside the pyspark shell), I shall just include this line of code in my Python script, correct?

Answer (score 8):

> Question : How can I change the setting and enable
>   spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled?

There are 3 options through which you can achive this.
1) modify the parameters mentioned below in the `spark-defaults.conf`
2) sending the below parameters from --conf from your `spark-submit`
3) Programatically specifying the config of dynamic allocation as demonstrated below.

out of which programatically you can do this way
You can do it in programmatic way like this.

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("ClusterManager")
      .setAppName("test-executor-allocation-manager")
      .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")
      .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors", 1)
      .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors", 2)
      .set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "true") // for stand alone
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Shall I include the script you provided here, to the pyspark I write? Or this is part of the configuration .sh file I should modify?

Comment: you have to include this in your python program file moreover above is scala syntax

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm writing Python script to send into pyspark. Let me try to modify what you suggest here and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue that affects Spark installations made using other resources as well, such as the spark-ec2 script for installing on Amazon Web Services.  From the Spark documentation, two values in SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf need to be set :

```
spark.shuffle.service.enabled   true
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled true
```

see this: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation

If your installation has a spark-env.sh script in SPARK_HOME/conf, make sure that it does not have lines such as the following, or that they are commented out:

```
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=1 #or some other integer, or
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_INSTANCES=1 #or some me other integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Configuration parameters can be set in pyspark via notebook using the following similar command:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answers, all configs mentioned may not work because of interpreter settings (if you use Zeppelin). I use Livy and its default settings override the dynamicAllocation parameters.

Comment: This can be a comment and not an answer.